# How to automatically colour a given block in Simulink?

Tags: layout, simulink

I would like to colour all occurrences of a specific block in Simulink. For instance, I want all `Scope`s to be yellow. How can I achieve this.

1. Is there a way to select all specific blocks at once?
2. When entering a new specific block, is there a way to automatically set its colour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to create a [library](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/creating-block-libraries.html#responsive_offcanvas) and have the blocks with the colours already set in it.

Alternatively you can use `find_all` to identify all blocks and `set_param(blockname,'BackgroundColor','green')` to change the coluor.